# Fit sine function to my data to find the starting and finishing points

Tags: fitting

Say that I have the following data

```
  DataX = {{3.4`, 
        2.2516679754406105`*^-8}, {3.5`, -8.796310947104858`*^-8}, {3.6`, 
        3.436206296498269`*^-7}, {3.7`, -1.3422706504309448`*^-6}, {3.8`, 
        5.243037187407348`*^-6}, {3.9`, -0.000020478942504723612`}, {4.`, 
        0.00007998593415536338`}, {4.1`, -0.0010107167248735436`}, {4.2`, 
        0.07388842736709378`}, {4.3`, 0.23004397985138975`}, {4.4`, 
        0.4329573622285607`}, {4.5`, 0.6502842635718505`}, {4.6`, 
        0.840613536036122`}, {4.7`, 0.9701213141038791`}, {4.8`, 
        1.0002146281022952`}, {4.9`, 0.9999647772216878`}, {5.`, 
        1.0002661612093822`}, {5.1`, 1.0001390743777006`}, {5.2`, 
        1.0001573874093896`}, {5.3`, 1.0000670562306497`}, {5.4`, 
        1.0000368355851015`}};
```

which represents a half wave.

I would like to place a sine function on top of my data points using the following information provided based on its analytical solution:

1. The maximum value is 1, Which in the numerical solution (DataX) is 1.00004.
2. The slope of the sine function, which according to DataX is 65.3 degree. (see the image)

[image]

3. The center of the curve. This is determined by normalizing the position of DataX to its maximum. So that the maximum would be 1. And then setting the position of the center of the half sine at 0.5.

Comment: I don't understand what are _starting and finishing points of the half wave_. Also, I find your comments confusing and contradictory: _I am not interested in fitting the data itself_ and _I want to fit a sine function on my data_. So you want to fit a function to the data without using the data...? (Are the `DataX` even relevant for this question, if you insist on using some 3 numbers derived from it?) Please provide more context, like the analytical solution you are using; and maybe a made-up example illustrating what you want to achieve.

Comment: @corey979 sorry if my question and comments were confusing. Please see the edited post.

Comment: Ad 2. The slope at what point? // What's the model? `a + b Sin[c x + d]`?

Comment: see the image please.

Comment: Do you just want to add a sine wave on the same plot as your data? This is not fitting but plotting two graphs on top of each other. Fitting has a particular meaning.

Comment: Yes. According to these pieces of information, I would like to add a sine wave. Sorry for the incorrect use of fitting.

Comment: What's the model...?

Comment: It is a sine function.

Comment: This is a sine: `Sin[x]`; this too: `Sin[c x]`; and this: `a+b Sin[c x+d]`. There are lots of other combinations of parameters that yield something that many could call a sine (exactly 16 for the set `{a,b,c,d}`). In particular, if you set all the parameters to zero, you'll get `0` - that's technically also a sine - just multiplied by zero. So, for the fourth time: what's the model???

Comment: @corey979 I have only 3 pieces of information. According to this information I want to write a sine function. So when I give you the amplitude, the position of the center and the maximum value, the function is simply $y=A \sin (B x + C)+D$

Comment: @Hugh who said that? It depends on period.

Comment: Please go back to pen and paper and think about how many conditions you have and how many free parameters your sine function has. Especially, think about what it means for the whole sine function if you fix the slope. I'm sure the result [does not look like you would expect it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k2uaC.png). What you try to do *is* possible, but I'm very unsure if you understand what the outcome will be.

Comment: This looks like Hill function. `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, x^n/(k^n + x^n), {k, n}, x];Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 7}], Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the equation $f(x)=A\sin(Bx+C)+D$.
Since the maximum value is $1$, the position of the center is $0.5$ (meaning that $f(0)=0.5$?) we get that the amplitude is $0.5$, vertical shift is $0.5$, and phase shift is $0$.

$f(x)=0.5\sin(Bx)+0.5$.

```
D[0.5 Sin[B x] + 0.5, x] /. x -> 0
(*0.5 B*)

0.5 B == Tan[65.3 \[Degree]] // NSolve
(*{{B -> 4.34831186512}}*)
```

Therefore, your sine function is

```
f[x_] := 0.5 + 0.5 Sin[4.348311865122983 x]
Show[ListPlot[DataX], Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]
It doesn't seem to fit well the half sine (x from 4 to 4.8), but if we shift it 0.1 to the right it seems to be better.

```
Show[ListPlot[DataX], Plot[f[x - 0.1], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let's go step-by-step with the requirements.

The model is

```
f[x_] := a + b Sin[c x + d]
```

The constraint are:

```
(* slope at x=0 *)
eq1 = (D[f[x], x] /. x -> 0) == Tan[65.3 Degree]

(* value at x=1/2 *)
eq2 = f[0.5] == 1

(* maximum value equals 1; we need to find local maxima & minima *)
minmax = x /. Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0, x]
```

[image]

```
f[minmax[[1]]] // Simplify
f[minmax[[2]]] // Simplify
```

[image]

In general, we don't know which one is the maximum and which is the minimum, so let's try both options:

```
Solve[{a - b == -1, a + b == 1}, {a, b}]
```

> {{a -> 0, b -> 1}}

```
Solve[{a - b == 1, a + b == -1}, {a, b}]
```

> {{a -> 0, b -> -1}}

We can't be sure about `b`, but for sure

```
a=0;
```

Let's start with `b=1`:

```
Block[{b = 1}, NSolve[{eq1, eq2}, {c, d}]]
```

doesn't return an answer. Let's make a substep:

```
Block[{b = 1}, Solve[eq1, c]]
```

> {{c -> 2.17416 Sec[d]}}

and input it in `eq2` (copy-paste):

```
NSolve[Sin[0.5` 2.1741559325614914` Sec[d] + d] == 1, d]
```

> NSolve[Sin[d + 1.08708 Sec[d]] == 1, d]

Still no answer, so

```
Plot[Sin[d + 1.0870779662807457` Sec[d]], {d, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Let's consider only $d\in[0,1]$:

```
Block[{b = 1}, Solve[eq1 && eq2 && 0 < d < 1, {c, d}]]
```

> {{c -> 2.35424, d -> 0.393675}}

So one solution can be `{a,b,c,d}={0,1,2.35424,0.393675}`

Similarly, the case `b=-1` leads to the plot:

[image]

but

```
Block[{b = -1}, Solve[eq1 && eq2 && -1.2 < d < -1, {c, d}]]
```

> {}

Let's zoom in:

[image]

```
FindArgMax[Sin[d - 1.0870779662807457` Sec[d]], {d, -1.25}]>
```

{-1.2513}

and

```
Sin[d - 1.0870779662807457` Sec[d]] /. d -> -1.2513
```

> 1.

so it looks like `NSolve` fails on accuracy. Nevertheless,

```
c -> -2.1741559325614914` Sec[d] /. d -> -1.2513
```

> c -> -6.92211

so the other set of solutions is `{a,b,c,d}={0,-1,-6.92211,-1.2513}`.

Note that the first two plots are plotted in a restricted range, and even in that range there are lots of (infinitely many?) local maxima, so with the given constraints there is no unique solution.

---

*The first version of the answer*

Is this what you're after?

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[DataX, a + b Sin[c x + d], {a, b, c, d}, x];
Normal@nlm
```

> 0.49297 - 0.581267 Sin[4.12402 - 2.35384 x]

```
Show[ListPlot[DataX], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 3.4, 5.4}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

1. `x0 = x /. NSolve[nlm[x] == .5 && 4 < x < 5, x][[1, 1]]`

   > 4.42651
2. `FindMaxValue[nlm[x], {x, 5}]`

   > 1.07424
3. `D[nlm[x], x] /. x -> x0`

   > 1.36811

Comment: Actually no. Because as I said I have these three numbers (center, maximum and slope) according to the analytical solution. And according to these numbers I want to fit a sine function on my data.

Comment: Plus, I am not interested in fitting the data itself, but by using the fitting data method I want to find the starting and finishing points of my half wave.

Comment: @MsenRezaee Even if this does not answer your real questions, you can use these concepts to work out the solution by yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I will surely use it :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but what happened as I started looking at your data. If I plot your data I get this:

```
ListPlot[DataX, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You say this is a half wave. This is not a half sine wave. We need more information on what you are doing. This looks more like an arctan.

Can you explain more?

Comment: I didn't say the data is a half sine. I said the data is a half wave and I would like to set a sine function on it. Analytically the solution is half sine but since this is a finite element solution, it does not appear to be a half sine wave.

Comment: @MsenRezaee Is it possible the solution should be a sigmoid and not a sine?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No because the analytical solution shows a sine function.